# How to prove this inequality? (proof of limit)

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, inequality

How can I prove that for every e that :

$|(5+n^2)^{1/n} - 1| < \epsilon$ ? (considering that n is a natural number).
I know by archemidian property that $1/n < \epsilon$, by can this help proving this inequality?

By the way I am proving that limit of $(5+n^2)^{1/n}$ as $n$ goes to infinity is $1.$

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$$
(5+n^2)^{1/n} = \exp\left(\frac{\ln(5+n^2)}{n}\right) = \exp\left(\frac{2\ln(n)+\ln(1+5/n^2)}{n}\right) = \exp(o(1))
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't think its that complicated, and how ln(5+n^2)=2ln(n) + ln(1+5/n^2) ?

Comment: Logarithms transform products into sums.